# What is the syntax of including not null value in dynamic soql and how to include a number variable in dynamic soql

Tags: dynamic-soql

```
var s = "Select Account_vod__c from Event_Speaker_AZ__c where ";
    s = s + " Medical_Event_AZ__c =  '" + "{!Medical_Event_vod__c.Id}" + "' " 
          +" AND  Join_URL_Status_Code_AZ__c = {!JoinURLStatusCode} AND Account_AZ__c != null";
```

I am converting this code into apex dynamic soql.
Join URL Status is a number field and I have declared `JoinURLStatusCode` as a Decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Best to use bind variables instead so there is no need to format various types and avoids the SOQL injection security risk. That is possible in dynamic as well as static SOQL, though in dynamic the variables have to be simple (no dotted expressions).

But your SOQL can be implemented as static SOQL so you get the benefit of compiler checking and explicit typing, so:

```
SomeSObjectType medical_Event_vod__c = ...;
Decimal joinURLStatusCode = ...;

Event_Speaker_AZ__c[] results = [
    Select Account_vod__c
    from Event_Speaker_AZ__c
    where Medical_Event_AZ__c = :medical_Event_vod__c.Id
    AND Join_URL_Status_Code_AZ__c = :joinURLStatusCode
    AND Account_AZ__c != null
];
```

The dynamic SOQL version would be:

```
SomeSObjectType medical_Event_vod__c = ...;
Decimal joinURLStatusCode = ...;
Id medicalEventId = medical_Event_vod__c.Id;

SObject[] results = Database.query(''
    + ' Select Account_vod__c'
    + ' from Event_Speaker_AZ__c'
    + ' where Medical_Event_AZ__c = :medicalEventId'
    + ' AND Join_URL_Status_Code_AZ__c = :joinURLStatusCode'
    + ' AND Account_AZ__c != null'
);
```

A couple of places where dynamic SOQL is needed are:

- Where you need to change the structure of the query at runtime rather than the values
- Where you don't want a dependency to be introduced e.g. where you are writing code that works with our without some other custom object (e.g. an optional managed package)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help. It worked.